# Catalog price rules just working a short time

Tags: catalog-price-rules, price-rules, catalog-rules

I´ve set up several catalog price rules. After applying them everything works fine.

Some days later (it´s a testshop and I dont look after the prices every day) the discounted prices showing up in frontend but if I click on the article the price rules arent active anymore -> first thing u see is a working price rule -> checkout or articlepage -> undiscounted price.

So i applied all the rules again and it worked (checkout too). 
That was about three days ago - now I´ve got the same problem and I got it working same way as before.

This shop will go live on january 1th so I´m a bit scared of checking it every day... I dont know why this happens neither when.

Maybe someone got this issue too? (catalog price rules seems to disapply in articlepage and checkout after some time)

Comment: Make sure that the Magento cron is running correctly.

Comment: @Simon this is correct, add it as answer.

Comment: @AhmedElAwadi done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Magento cron is running correctly. This should solve the problem.